# Only receiving errors when website is hosted

Tags: c#, asp.net, server, object-reference

I'm running into an issue that is completely out of my scope of knowledge. I've done alot of research and nothing seems to fit my situation so I appreciate any and all help!

So I'm developing this application confirms user's identity. It calls the method "verify" which is written in the .aspx.cs file  It then does some processing in the .aspx.cs file that includes accessing various controls on the page.

When I compile and run on my local machine, all is good. Runs perfectly. The issue I'm having is when I publish to my server, Im receiving a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error.

> [STACK TRACE]
>
> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
    VerifyIdentity._Default.verify(String firstName, String lastName, String street, String zip) +1512
    VerifyIdentity._Default.Button3_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +159
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9692626
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +108         


 System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
    System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
    System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3562

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1069.1
```

This is the stack trace I am receiving.

Here is the region of code where the error is tracing back to:

```
string firstName = tbFirstName.Text;
string lastName = tbLastName.Text;
string street = tbStreet.Text;
string zip = tbZip.Text;

List<Question> questions = verify(firstName, lastName, street, zip);
```

I am truly at a lost here and need some sort of direction. Thank you for any and all help! I can include whatever files you need me to in order to determine where this is happening.

Comment: Please post code of `verify` function.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that any (or all) of those 4 variables are null. Though as Mairaj points out, we don't know, because the *actual* exception happens inside `verify`. If it truly only happens when deployed, and you are entering values into each text box, I would write some defensive checks to find *which* value is null, and then throw an appropriate exception when found, so you can investigate further.

Comment: In your case I would recommend you to check your web.config - maybe there is a difference on how they implement viewstate on hosted environment. Be aware that settings may get overwritten by application.config if not correctly specified.